# Installation of Cordova on Ubuntu gives "...cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126: error

Tags: android, cordova, ubuntu

I am installing Cordova on Ubuntu and followed [these](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/index.html) instruction on Cordova site:

All is well until I come to this step:

```
cordova emulate android
```

I get the following error:

```
Running command: /home/eisen/android/hello/platforms/android/cordova/run --emulator
ANDROID_HOME=/home/eisen/android/android-sdk-linux
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

/home/eisen/android/hello/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                throw e;
                ^
Error executing "adb devices": /home/eisen/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb: 1: /home/eisen/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb: Syntax error: ")" unexpected

Error: /home/eisen/android/hello/platforms/android/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 1
```

This error is discussed elsewhere and always refers to correcting the PATH and ANDROID_HOME variables. That has not helped me. Here are my settings of these variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME=/home/eisen/android/android-sdk-linux
ANDROID_SDK=/home/eisen/android/android-sdk-linux
PATH=...:/home/eisen/android/android-sdk-linux:/home/eisen/android/android-sdk-linux/tools:/home/eisen/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
```

The ... in the PATH refers to other directories which are not relevant to the question.

...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get through the error by installing android-tools-adb which is not documented in the installation procedure:

```
sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb
```

Comment: Worked for me . Thanks